# string subscript out of range

Tags: c++, arrays, string, loops

I'm trying to display the accurate word after other word, which has 8 characters. Unfortunately there shows an error about string subscript out of range. I know that the problem is with the loop, but I don't know how to solve it. Why "line[j] != '('" dosen't work?

```
getline(myFile, line);
size_t pos = line.find(arrayTypeOne[i]); //finding position
if (pos != string::npos)
{
    for (int j = pos + 9; line[j] != '('; j++)
        cout << line[j];
}//if
```

**I solved it. The problem was in different place. I'm so sorry, I'll think twice next time. Thanks for help**

Comment: You realize that there is nothing limiting the `j` variable from going past the end of the string.

Comment: Using pen and paper, take the case of a 10 character string and that the `pos` variable will be set to 0.  Also, the string doesn't have a '(' in it.

Comment: I do, but a sign "(" is in the line (my string) at 21 position and then it should break the loop

Comment: *"It should break the loop"*, and what if there is no '(' in the string?  Did your program generate the string?  Is it a constant?  If not, then you can't trust its contents.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible chance that there is no '(' in the string.  In this case, you keep incrementing the `j` variable without checking if the `j` variable has gone past `line.length()`.

I suggest adding an *and* condition where you check if `j` is past the length of the string.

**Edit 1: Searching again**
Can you avoid the loop and use:

```
line.find('(', pos + 1);
```

Comment: But there is! My string:

     INSTANCE Schutzring_Geschosse2(C_Item)

Comment: Then use a debugger to find out why it is not failing.  Hint:  add a print statement in the loop that prints out the value of `j` and the length of the string.

Comment: If There is a '(' at exactly the multiples of 9 somewhere in your string, then it should work....But as suggested, it might be at some other position...Is it at exactly a multiple of 9 ??